# StringBuilder("...").ToString() and new String() behaves differently. Why?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

In the following tests: how the results of `str == str2` and `x == y` can be different?

```
[Test]
public void StringsAreImmutableObjects()
{
    String str = new String(new char[] {'a', 'l', 'i'});
    String str2 = new String(new char[] {'a', 'l', 'i'});

    Assert.AreEqual("ali", str);
    Assert.AreEqual("ali", str2);

    /*
    * Strange!
    *
    * C# has two "equals" concepts: Equals and ReferenceEquals.
    * For most classes you will encounter, the == operator uses
    * one or the other (or both), and generally only tests for
    * ReferenceEquals when handling reference types (but the
    * string Class is an instance where C# already knows how
    * to test for value equality).
    */

    Assert.AreEqual(str, str2);
    Assert.IsTrue(str == str2);
    Assert.IsTrue(Equals(str, str2));
    Assert.IsFalse(ReferenceEquals(str, str2));

    object x = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();
    object y = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();

    Assert.IsTrue(x.Equals(y));
    Assert.IsTrue(object.Equals(x, y));
    Assert.IsFalse(x == y);
    Assert.IsFalse(ReferenceEquals(x, y));
}
```

The following tests will also pass:

```
Assert.IsTrue(str is string);
Assert.IsTrue(str2 is string);
Assert.IsTrue(x is string);
Assert.IsTrue(y is string);
```

Comment: System.Object does not provide an operator overload for operator==().  String does.  Just declare the x/y variable correctly, ought to be string.

Comment: @HansPassant .ToString being called before equity check. I think they are declared correctly.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN: The declared type for the variable `x` is `object`. That’s how the operator overload is selected. Doesn’t matter what it contains.

Comment: Hmm got it. Thanks for help!